# How to change the design of my table in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to change the design of my table in r. In this case, i have the next table:

```
cluster   sales_1    sales_2
1          500000    130000
2          400000    200000
3          300000    145000
4          30000     10000
```

And i want to get the next design:

```
Cluster    sales      Total
1          sales_1    500000
2          sales_1    400000
3          sales_1    300000       
4          sales_1    30000     
1          sales_2    130000
2          sales_2    200000
3          sales_2    145000
4          sales_2    10000
```

Any help or idea will be great!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
new <- df %>% pivot_longer(-cluster) %>%
  arrange(name)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  cluster name     value
    <int> <chr>    <int>
1       1 sales_1 500000
2       2 sales_1 400000
3       3 sales_1 300000
4       4 sales_1  30000
5       1 sales_2 130000
6       2 sales_2 200000
7       3 sales_2 145000
8       4 sales_2  10000
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(cluster = 1:4, sales_1 = c(500000L, 400000L, 300000L, 
30000L), sales_2 = c(130000L, 200000L, 145000L, 10000L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```